# Load test REST service without cache

Tags: wcf, rest, caching, soapui, load-testing

I am trying to load test a WCF REST service with SoapUI . The service is configured with `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode Single`. I am using Fiddler to view the response messages as I was unable to find how to do this in load test of SoapUI (maybe can't be done). I am expecting to see the first response to be different than all the others, but I think that the resource is being cached during load test and I always get same response for all the requests. I experienced the same in web browser and since I use jQuery AJAX method, solution was to use

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Is there a way to do this kind of testing in SoapUI or any other tool? Or am I wrong thinking that this is a caching problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try sending the header `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache` and see if that helps.

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll throw up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending this header should take care of it:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
```